# React router 6 (data router) redirect with data

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

Using the data router in React-Router 6 I want to redirect the user from an action, but also I need to return data. Can you do both at the same time?

Redirect works, but no way to send data.

```js
export async function routerAction() {
  return redirect("/some-url");
}
```

Should work, but does not.

```js
export async function routerAction() {
  return new Response(JSON.stringify({ foo: "bar" }), {
    status: 302,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json; utf-8",
      Location: "/some-url",
    },
  });
}
```

In my component I try to retrieve the data like this:

```js
function SomeComponent() {
  let actionData = useActionData(); // unfortunately, actionData is undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8059718/8690857) it would seem that modern browsers simply ignore the message body of 302 responses.

> As far as I know, all modern browsers ignore the message body of a 302
> in response to a GET or POST and will directly go to the URL as
> specified in `Location` header.

What I can suggest then is to just return a JSON response which includes the data ***and*** redirect target back to the component submitting the action, then use a `useEffect` hook to effect an imperative redirect to the target route with the data payload.

Example:

```js
import { json } from 'react-router-dom';

const action = ({ request }) => {
  return json({
    data: { foo: "bar" },
    redirect: "/some-url"
  });
};
```

```js
const ComponentA = () => {
  const actionData = useActionData();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (actionData) {
      const { data, redirect } = actionData;
      navigate(redirect, { state: data, replace: true });
    }
  }, [actionData, navigate]);

  return (
    <>
      ...
      <Form method="post">
        ...
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </Form>
    </>
  );
};
```

Instead of using the `useActionData` hook use the `useLocation` hook to access the passed route state.

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const { state } = useLocation();

  ...
};
```

### Demo

[image: Edit react-router-6-data-router-redirect-with-data]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have to find different way to pass data into other component.
`useActionData()` only returns the data when you use `<Form method="post">` or `useSubmit()`