Remix React return json and redirect
In Remix, how do you return json first and then redirect after a success call on the API?
export const action: ActionFunction = async ({
    request,
}: ActionFunctionArgs) => {
    const formData = await request.formData();

    try {
        const { project } = await sampleAPICall(formData);
        return json({
            title: "Success",
            message: "Yehey!",
        });

        throw redirect(`/${project?.id}`); 
    } catch (error) {
        return json({
            variant: "destructive",
            message: "Oh no....",
        });
    }
};


Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77725648/8690857

@DrewReese. Great. Is there any difference performance wise between your answer and the one answered below by Kiliman?

No, it's basically the same answer. Not close enough to be marked a true duplicate, but provides a bit more detail. I like Kiliman's session flash suggestion. There's a ton of overlap in features and shared code between Remix-run and the client-side react-router libraries they also maintain, one of them being the Data APIs and routers and loaders, etc.

Redirects can't have a body, so you can't include a JSON payload in a redirect. If you want to display a message on the redirected route, you would typically use session flash.
https://remix.run/docs/en/main/utils/sessions#sessionflashkey-value
import { commitSession, getSession } from "../sessions";

export async function action({
  params,
  request,
}: ActionFunctionArgs) {
  const session = await getSession(request.headers.get("Cookie"));
  const formData = await request.formData;
  const { project } = await sampleAPICall(formData);
  session.flash("message", { title: "Success", message: "Yehey!" });

  return redirect("`/${project?.id}`, {
    headers: {
      "Set-Cookie": await commitSession(session),
    },
  });
}

Then in your project route, you can display the message from flash
import { json } from "@remix-run/node";
import { useLoaderData } from "@remix-run/react";
import { getSession, commitSession } from "./sessions";

export async function loader({ request } LoaderFunctionArgs) {
  const session = await getSession(request.headers.get("Cookie"));
  const message = session.get("message") || null;

  return json(
    { message },
    {
      headers: {
        // only necessary with cookieSessionStorage
        "Set-Cookie": await commitSession(session),
      },
    }
  );
}

export default function Component() {
  const { message } = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();

  return (
    <div>
      {message ? (
        <div className="flash">{message.title} {message.message}</div>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
}


Is this also ok? what's the disadvantage of this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77725648/react-router-6-data-router-redirect-with-data

The Remix/Flash solution is how you handle it server-side. The React Router one shows how to do it on the client (where you return the redirect URL and call navigate in your component). This is basically what I said in the comment to Ilia's answer below.

Thank you. But is there an advantage doing it server side? Is it better? Is it faster performance wise?

If you're already using Remix, you should probably do it server-side. The nice thing is that it will work whether you have JavaScript on the client or not.

I think you need to structure your code to handle the redirection separately from the JSON response. You cannot have code that executes after a return statement.
export const action: ActionFunction = async ({
    request,
    redirect,
}: ActionFunctionArgs) => {
    const formData = await request.formData();

    try {
        const { project } = await sampleAPICall(formData);
        return json({
            title: "Success",
            message: "Yehey!",
            redirectTo: `/${project?.id}`, // Include redirection URL in JSON response
        });
    } catch (error) {
        return json({
            variant: "destructive",
            message: "Oh no....",
        });
    }
};

export const loader: LoaderFunction = ({ json }) => {
    return json();
};


Hopefully I was able to help! Best of luck! :)

You should also note that since the redirect is not happening on the server, you'll need to handle that in the UI component. const navigate = useNavigate(); const data = useActionData(); if (data?.redirectTo) navigate(data.redirectTo);
